# Cloning input type file and set the value

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, file-upload, input

I know that it isn't possible to set the value of an input type="file" for security reasons...

My problem is:

I needed to style an input type="file" so what I did was have a button and hide the file input. like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('input[name=&quot;photo1&quot;]').click(); return false;" id="photo1-link"></a>
<input type="file" name="photo1" class="fileInput jqtranformdone validate[required]" id="photo1" />
```

These works great in all browsers except IE which gives me an access denied error on submitting through ajax.

I'm using the ajaxSubmit jquery plugin (malsup.com/jquery/form/)

So after reading for a while I tried to do:

```
var photo1Val = $('#photo1').val();
var clone1 = $('#photo1').clone().val(photo1Val);
$('#photo1').remove();

clone1.appendTo('form');
console.log(photo1Val) //prints the right value C:/fakepath/blablabla.jpg
$('form').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

The problem is that after this the value of $('#photo1') is empty... Any ideas how to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: more detail please, you removed $('#photo1') and as such it's value will be gone, right?

Comment: nop. I store the value in photo1Val. See the console.log I just inserted in the question please

Comment: ok, I'm not sure entirely, but you might want to check if callinng .val() on a file upload input was what you intended to do, cause I'm a bit busy here

Comment: but you might want to heck? Sorry didn't understand

Comment: It gives me the correct value before removing and appending... I don't think the problem is in getting the value I think it has to be while setting

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you got the problem wrong. First I need file input (not text). Second I need to try to prevent ie from finding out that the file input was called through javascript. Otherwise it will give me the access denied error.